# Why does Chrome only honor YouTube embedded URL start and end parameters in Incognito Mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, url-parameters, incognito-mode

I've got a page that has a bunch of YouTube videos where I've embedded start and end codes in there to ensure only a segment of the video is played instead of the whole thing.

For example:

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YGOpjPNtjes?iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&start=2964&end=3397" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

[Play Video (YouTube embed)](http://www.youtube.com/embed/YGOpjPNtjes?iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&start=2964&end=3397)

If the above is played in stock Google Chrome with no extensions, it should start at 49:24 but instead starts at 49:27, which is three seconds off. However, if viewed using Chrome's incognito mode, it starts at the right time of 49:24.

This may only be a situation where the symptom occurs when there is both a start and end time present in the URL.

Why is it that Google Chrome disrespects the start time, and is there anything I can do about it that wouldn't have downstream impacts like affecting the start time in other browsers? Seems like a bug in Chrome since no other browser I've tested exhibits this behavior. Done lots of research, but it doesn't seem like anybody's noticing this or talking about it.

Comment: Have you tried this on a clean install? My guess is that you have an extension that interacts with your page (which gets disabled by Incognito Mode).

Comment: Yes, a stock install of Chrome with no extensions on Windows 7 exhibits this behavior. Same on Mac. Try for yourself, if you have Chrome... it's really weird.

I, too, thought it was extension-related, which is why I tried Incognito mode.

Comment: It works fine for me, that's why i asked.

Comment: Works fine for me as well.  Have version of Chrome do you have @MichaelPaul?

Comment: Latest version... Version 31.0.1650.57 m
 
Google Chrome is up to date.